# C# possibilities tree from integers array

Tags: c#, arrays, tree

How can i build possibilities tree from integers array with C#? I need to make all possibles variants of array if in the every step delete one element from array.

example if we have array from three integers [1,2,3] then tree should looks like this: [tree view](http://adasu.info/tree.png)

Comment: Well, what are you stuck on - working out the permutations, or putting them into a tree?

Comment: i need the algorithm which makes tree from array (like in my picture)

Comment: in the picture... I would expect the labels to either get longer (1, 13, 132) or shorter (123, 13, 3), or be one token each (1, 3, 2) - it is inclear what (1, 23, 2) / (2, 13, 1) means - can you clarify?

Comment: Okay, so what have you come up with so far? And why does the *middle* column have 2 digits, but the others only one? And why do you only have one branch off each of the middle nodes, instead of two? What would the results be for an array of 1, 2, 3, 4? (No need for a picture - put it in text in your question.)

Comment: hmm yes my pic is a bit confusing, look again i updated picture, i hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this as a binary arithmetic problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
    PickElements(0, arr);
}

static void PickElements<T>(int depth, T[] arr, int mask = -1)
{
    int bits = Math.Min(32, arr.Length);
    // keep just the bits from mask that are represented in arr
    mask &= ~(-1 << bits); 
    if (mask == 0) return;

    // UI: write the options
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++ )
        Console.Write('>'); // indent to depth
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((mask & (1 << i)) != 0)
        {
            Console.Write(' ');
            Console.Write(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    // recurse, taking away one bit (naive and basic bit sweep)
    for (int i = 0; i < bits; i++)
    {
        // try and subtract each bit separately; if it
        // is different, recurse
        var childMask = mask & ~(1 << i);
        if (childMask != mask) PickElements(depth + 1, arr, childMask);
    }
}
```

For a `TreeView`, simply replace the `Console.Write` etc with node creation, presumably passing the parent node in (and down) as part of the recursion (in place of `depth`, perhaps).

---

To see what this is doing, consider the binary; -1 is:

```
11111111111111...111111111111111
```

we then look at `bits`, which we derive from the array length, and find to be 3 in this example. We only need to look at 3 bits, then; the line:

```
~(-1 << bits)
```

computes a mask for this, because:

```
-1          = 1111111....1111111111111
(-1 << 3)   = 1111111....1111111111000 (left-shift back-fills with 0)
~(-1 << 3)  = 0000000....0000000000111 (binary inverse)
```

we then apply this to our input mask, so we're only ever looking at the least significant 3 bits, via `mask &= ...`. If that turns out to be zero, we've run out of things to do, so stop recursing.

The UI update is simple enough; we just scan over the 3 bits that we care about, checking whether the current bit is "on" for our mask; `1 << i` creates a mask with just the "i-th set bit"; the `&` and `!= 0` checks whether that bit is set. If it is, we include the element in the output.

Finally, we need to start *taking away* bits, to look at the sub-tree; we *could* probably be more sophisticated about this, but I chose just to scan all the bits and try them - worst case this is 32 bit tests per level, which is nothing. As before, `1 << i` creates a mask of just the "i-th set bit". This time we want to *disable* that bit, so we "negate" and "and" via `mask & ~(...)`. It is possible that this bit was *already* disabled, so the `childMask != mask` check ensures we only *actually* recurse when we have disabled a bit that was previously enabled.

The end result is that we end up with the masks being successively:

```
11..1111111111111111 (special case for first call; all set)
   110   (first bit disabled)
      100   (first and second bits disabled)
      010   (first and third bits disabled)
   101   (second bit disabled)
      100   (second and first bits disabled)
      001   (second and third bits disabled)
   011   (third bit disabled)
      010   (third and first bits disabled)
      001   (third and second bits disabled)
```

Note that for a **simpler** combination example, it would be possible to **just** iterate in a single `for`, using the bits to pick elements; however, I've done it a recursive way because  we need to build a tree of successive subtractions, rather than just flat possibilities in no particular order.